# options != null "FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Basically i am taking online course on Udemy.  I was copying the same code as as the instructor were typing but got error every time.

I asked the instructor about error.  he messaged this to me. But i don't know  how to write this in code.

(    solution for that. that is you have to pass the apiKey: , appId: , messagingSenderId: , projected: to Firebase.initializeApp(option: FirebaseOption()) parameter then  it is working fine. i hope this will help to others.    )

can someone please help explain to me that how to do it. or change my code will be a lot easier for me.

thanks in advance.

```
<script>
  const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDuh40Sg-78K6CMC3ByFCubgZE4M2tAcfQ",
  authDomain: "tick-it-f1cfe.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "tick-it-f1cfe",
  storageBucket: "tick-it-f1cfe.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "300475381561",
  appId: "1:300475381561:web:74ae76163157cb07101ae8",
  measurementId: "G-BFNKZR1P6S"
};

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

</script>
```

help me understand this answer to me.

Answer (score -1):

You could try changing **const** to **var** because it doesn't really seem right but. What programming language is this and what is it for specifically?

```
<script>

  var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDuh40Sg-78K6CMC3ByFCubgZE4M2tAcfQ",
  authDomain: "tick-it-f1cfe.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "tick-it-f1cfe",
  storageBucket: "tick-it-f1cfe.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "300475381561",
  appId: "1:300475381561:web:74ae76163157cb07101ae8",
  measurementId: "G-BFNKZR1P6S"
};

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

</script>
```

Comment: this is flutter programing. i am trying to connect my web portal with firebase. this code is from index.html

Comment: Have you fully read through the [Firebase Setup w/ Flutter Doc?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)